# ¿Cómo averiguar la procedencia de una rama determinada?

Tags: git

Si tengo tres ramas *master*, *develop* y *xxx*. ¿Hay alguna forma de averiguar mediante comandos de que rama parte *xxx*? ¿y ya que estamos, que ramas parten de una rama determinada?

> Editado

Lo que me gustaría saber es si se puede preguntar por una rama concreta o si se puede obtener un listado de ramas como:

```
master
master/develop
master/develop/xxx
master/develop/zzzzz
master/new-fonts
```

para verlo de forma sencilla.

Comment: Con gitk no te sirve? `gitk --all --date-order &` (el & es para que se ejecute paralelamente, sin tener que cerrar la ventana para seguir con el funcionamiento de la consola)

Comment: @msabate Si estoy viendo las ramas con este comando, pero muy claro no esta. Creo que me perdí la última vez que tuve que coger el metro con ese plano.

Comment: Git no te da un comando para ello, porque en general el concepto de "rama" es muy flexible. Puedes "borrar" una rama una vez mezclada, y lo que borras en realidad es su nombre, pero no los commits que contiene, puedes renombrar ramas... Dicho esto, puede lograrse de formas retorcidas. Mira [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch) o [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/finding-what-branch-a-git-commit-came-from)

Comment: Podrías subir la imagen para ver si podemos ayudarte, de todos modos si es algo privado entiendo que no puedas hacerlo. También puedes mirar el historial de commits usando `git log`. Encontrarás más info sobre el comando [aquí](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Comment: @Orici para listar ramas puedes usar `git branch -a`para ver todas las ramas (remotas y locales) y/o `git branch -r`para ver sólo las remotas. Debería devolverte un resultado igual al que comentas

Comment: @msabate con `git branch -a` si veo lo que quiero en las remotas, necesitaría poder verlo también en las locales

Comment: @Orici el `-a`es para todas, tanto locales como remotas

Comment: Prueba `git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%d' --all` Sigue mostrando un laberinto, pero bastante simplificado con respecto a `gitk`.

Comment: @abulafia mejor que con el gitk, pero no es exactamente lo que buscaba porque todavía hay que interpretarlo. Me apunto el comando de todas formas.

Comment: Me parece que lo que quieres hacer no se puede, o llegado el caso solo para un instante determinado. Ten en cuenta que las ramas(sobretodo máster)  deben ir integrando los cambios que vayan surgiendo. Si x ejemplo  creas la rama xxx desde máster, haces cambios y luego los mergeas sobre máster... Cual sería el origen de xxx? Ya no será máster... Otra cosa son los nodos (commits) de tu jerarquia. Quizás si cada vez que creas rama crearás un tag, podrías ver la estructura que dices...

Comment: @Jakala yo entiendo que la rama origen de una rama es aquella en la que estas situado cuando la creas, no se si voy desencaminado... También me parece que una rama no es más que un mecanismo para realizar cambios "en paralelo" por decirlo de algún modo a el trabajo que ya tienes en el punto de partida y que después incorporas a este, o no, por lo que realmente no existe hasta que guardas algún trabajo en ella.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los nombres MASTER, DEVELOP, RAMA-A... todos esos nombres son indices creados en un momento, que luego a medida que haces commit y merge en cada uno de ellos cambia su posicion. El problema es que no queda reflejado en git las fechas de cuando una rama fue master, o develop, o lo que sea... lo que queda es el id del commit, puesto que los indices van subiendo a medida que vas mergeando... Lo dicho, no creo que se pueda hacer CON RAMAS (quizas con tags seria otra historia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haz un checkout a la rama en cuestión y luego ejecuta:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
```

Así podrás identificar lo que necesitas.

Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Había algunas respuestas similares pero faltaba indicar `--oneline` para poder visualizarlo... de otra forma las líneas de las ramas se extienden demasiado y no se pueden apreciar, a no ser que existan muy pocos commits entre ramificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git log --graph --decorate`.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver todas las ramas:

```
git branch -a
```

Y para ver los diferentes commits de cada rama de forma ordenada:

```
git log --all --decorate  --graph --color
```